# Gson: serializing a java.nio.Path causes a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Serializing this, causes a StackOverFlowError :

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Tmp{
    private Path path=null;
    public Tmp() {
        path=Paths.get("c:\\temp\\");
    }
}
```

It looks like a bug to me ! Or I'm doing something wrong ?
Is there workaround (expect writing some custom serializer that converts the path to String)

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:372)

    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:381)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:376)
    ...
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:128)

    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:75)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:358)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getFieldAdapter(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:109)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.access$100(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:46)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:83)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
    ...
```

Serializing method is:

```
public static void saveTo(BatchLogging logging, Path path) throws IOException {
    Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    // String json = gson.toJson(logging);
    String json = gson.toJson(new Tmp());
    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(json.split(System.lineSeparator()));
    Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36964995/1032167 more info. Create custom `class PathConverter implements JsonDeserializer<Path>, JsonSerializer<Path>`  and register it as `.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Path.class, new MyPathConverter())`

Answer (score 3):

Examine the object returned by `Paths.get("c:\\temp\\");` in a debugger. On my machine, it has a field named `fs` that contains a `WindowsFileSystem`. This, in turn, has a field `provider` that contains a `WindowsFileSystemProvider` - and `provider` has a field `theFileSystem` which contains the same `WindowsFileSystem` as the original `fs` field does. Voila, cyclic reference.

Gson uses reflection to inspect and serialize, recursively, every non-transient field in the object you give it. A cyclic reference like this sends it into infinite recursion, which ends in `StackOverflowError`. To fix this, you will need to either implement custom serialization or serialize a specific property of the `Path` rather than the whole object. Marking any or all of the fields involved in the cycle as `transient` would also work, but that would require write access to the library's code.

Comment: I understand that. But in the same time, this class is a core Java class since Java 7 and should be handled correctly by Gson. I don't find it sound that every developer must implement his own serializer/deserializer for this class. This should be a core feature of Gson.

Comment: @lvr123 It doesn't implement `Serializable` and its purpose is mostly to parse, validate, manipulate, and otherwise use data, not to store it. Neither Gson nor any other serialization library has a good reason to give it special handling because serialization is not what `Path` is for. Map and the many subinterfaces of Collection have data storage as their primary purpose, and Gson does have special handling for those.

Comment: What do you propose to serialize this type of Object ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `ExclusionStrategy` to exclude certain types of classes or you can use `GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter` to implement custom serialization/deserialization.
[check out the docs](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html)