# How to serialize java.nio.file.Path with Gson?

Tags: java, gson, nio

I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when trying to serialize `Object` that contains `java.nio.file.Path`

Even when i wrote:

```
public class PathConverter implements JsonDeserializer<Path>, JsonSerializer<Path> {
    @Override
    public Path deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        return Paths.get(jsonElement.getAsString());
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Path path, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(path.toString());
    }
}
```

and apply it:

```
    String json = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Path.class, new PathConverter())
            .create()
            .toJson(constructorSetup, new TypeToken<ConstructorSetup>() {}.getType());
```

I still can't serialize this class:

```
public class ConstructorSetup {

    private Path appIconMimmapDirPathOnPc;

}
```

Stacktrace: (full on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5LUsZWb2))

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
        ...
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:380)
    at com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:355)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
        ...
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.<init>(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:118)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Please also show the `StackOverflowError` stacktrace.

Comment: Why would you serialize a `Path`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your problem is that `Path` is an `interface`. Let's suppose you used `Paths.get("/")` which will create instance of something like `WindowsPath` on my Windows PC. Now, you have to tell GSON how to deserialize this type:

```
ConstructorSetup setup = new ConstructorSetup();
setup.setAppIconMimmapDirPathOnPc(Paths.get("/"));

// here we get actual class type of our Path object
Class classT = setup.getAppIconMimmapDirPathOnPc().getClass();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(classT, new MyPathConverter())
```

Another approach you can go with is to `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`:

```
.registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Path.class, new MyPathConverter())
```

The purpose of typeHierarchyAdapter is to cover the case when you want the same representation for all subtypes of a type, which is exactly your case with `Path`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter` — what I need.

Comment: What is a `MyPathConverter` and what does it do?