# Serialize java.nio.file.Path with JsonBuilder in Groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy, json-serialization, jsonbuilder

I am trying to serialize an object which holds an instance of `java.nio.file.Path` and since `path` is an interface I am receiving a `StackOverflow Exception`

I have checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966590/11325201
and wanted to implement a type adapter for my use case in `groovy` but I didn't find `JsonBuilder`'s equivalent of `GsonBuilder`'s `registerTypeAdapter` or `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter`

How can I achieve a similar solution in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `JsonGenerator` object to your builder when you construct it. This object allows you to specify various options, including type converters, which you register with the `Class` and a closure. In this example, the converter just calls the `toString` on the Path.

```
def generator = new JsonGenerator.Options()
                                 .addConverter(Path) { Path p -> p.toString() }
                                 .build()                 

def json = new JsonBuilder(myObjContainingPathProperties, generator).toPrettyString()
```

The [online GroovyDocs for JsonGenerator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/) do not show anything (likely a GroovyDoc generator bug in version 3.0), but the [GroovyDocs for 2.5 work](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.9/html/api/groovy/json/JsonGenerator.Options.html).

Comment: Unfortunately I am limited by corporate packages - and they are Groovy 2.4.5 which doesn't have JsonGenerator. Is there another option?

Comment: It's not very elegant, but you could convert your object to a `Map`, replacing all `Path` values with corresponding `String` representations. And then you'd serialize the Map instead of the object.